# Thematic map with points QGIS

Tags: qgis, thematic-map, map-point

I would like know how can I make a thematic map (soybean production) with density points.

In this case the points are randomly plotted in a municipality area.

Please, see an example in the image: [image: Brazilian Soy Prod.]

Comment: Please explain how your map should look like. Do you want every state coloured in respect of the amount of production? Or a heatmap around your points? What data is stored in your point layer?

Comment: Please clarify: Is the example what you want to achieve or does it show the data you currently have? Give details about your input data.

Comment: I already have a .dbf file with soybean production by municipalities. However i don't know how to make the map showed above in QGIS. I just want to know how can i do that using points (which one represents 50,000 tons).

Comment: Do you have the municipalities as polygons?

Comment: Yes...I already have the .shp e .shx files too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **join** functionality to join the information about soybean production to the municipality geometries. Then use the **random points** tool in Vector | Research tools | Random points (http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html) to create points based on the soy bean production values. The tool will create points according to the production values. If the values are too high and would therefore cause creation of too many points, use the field calculator to calculate a new lower value first.